# Copy consolidated row data from multiple worksheets where a specific column is populated

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to copy a range of data from multiple worksheets to a single Summary sheet based upon a specific column being populated.

I'm using the code found on the link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793964(v=office.12).aspx
under the section entitled 'Copying All Data Except Column Headers from Multiple Worksheets'

It works although I've been trying to modify the code so that instead of copying the whole sheet, it copies only rows in which column 'N' is populated.

I disabled the line of code that sets CopyRng to the whole sheet and introduced a For loop to check the N column - I got the program to return any values which were present inside Column N across all the sheets but I need to return the entire rows of these instances.

Here is my modified code for the section in question :

```
        ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
        ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

            'Set the range that you want to copy
            'Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))


                For Each cell In sh.Range("N4:N4")
                     If (cell.Value <> "") Then

                     Set CopyRng = '(trying to copy the entire row here..)

                    End If
                Next
```

Could anyone help in regard to how I would go about setting CopyRng return the entire row?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Set CopyRng = cell.EntireRow
```

That should select the whole row for you to copy. However I'd be slightly timid about using it if you're doing a lot of copy and pasting as it selects many cells that you won't need. If you know the maximum extent of your data in columns then it might be better to use

```
Set CopyRng = Worksheets(SHEET_YOU_WANT).Range("A" & cell.row & ":" & furthestColumn & cell.row)
```

As this will take less time to complete.

Comment: Thanks very much, that works nicely. Though curiously it outputs the last record 3 times -    Re: Your suggestion, I'm using a For loop to read all the sheets :     ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 1)) = "_" Then

Comment: Thanks very much, that works nicely. 

Though curiously it outputs the last record 3 times. Any idea why this may be?


Re: Your suggestion, I'm using a For loop to read all the sheets :    

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 1)) = "_" Then


For each row copied, I was thinking about somehow plucking only data from certain columns, there is some data I don't need.

Comment: I'm not sure about outputting the last record three times, but if you only want to select a reduced number of cells in rows then you can use the Union function to join a number of continuous ranges together. If you then copy that range and paste it then it will paste as a continuous range